# remove class active from first parent in accordion

Tags: jquery, class, accordion, parent

i have the following problem. when i click any li element it adds class active but when I click li element to expand second level menu it adds class active and that is correct but when i click for example Second Level Link it adds class active but the parent li with ul inside still has class active how to remove this class???

```
<ul class="nav-stacked">
<li><a href="#">Link</a>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
<ul class="dropdown">
<li><a href="#">Second Level Link</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
        $(".nav-stacked > li").click(function() {
        $(".nav-stacked > li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        });
```

Comment: It's not clear waht you're asking... I see no code adding a class to a   `ul` here, and from where I see it the behaviour of your event is waht is expected... can you make a jsFiddle reproducing the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try removing all active classes and after add again the active class?

```
$(".nav-stacked > li").click(function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this:
 $(".nav-stacked > li").click(function() {
   $(".active").each(function(){
     $(this).removeClass("active");
   });
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: You should add some explanation along with the code.

Comment: First you should remove the "active" class from all the elements and then add the class to the required element. This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this same problem myself all day. I am trying to make a sidemenu for a tabbed space.

I tried getting the root node on click of any node, and then remove the 'active' class from all nodes that have it. lastly I add 'active class to the current node.

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hyp19nd5/2/)

```
$(".nav-stacked > li").click(function() {

    var firstUL = document.getElementById("sidebar"); //get root node
    var listItem = firstUL.getElementsByTagName("li"); //get all child li

    //loop through childen and remove  active from all that have it.
    for (var i=0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
        console.log(listItem[i].id);

        if(listItem[i].className == "active"){
        $(listItem[i].id).removeClass("active");
        }
        else
        console.log(listItem[i].id + ' does not have active class');
    }

    $(this).addClass("active");

});
```

this does remove 'active' from all elements but it fails on the adding it because 'this' always seems to be a parent node, and not the node clicked.

On a side note I found a solution that works for me and I thought I would share it because it is so simple I didn't think about it at first either.

Don't use nested ul elements or js. make a ul, fill with li, and add the 'subitem' class to all the elements considered child elements. finally write some css that indents the subitems.

If this isn't the look / functionality you are going for please ignore.
 [Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zn8v489z/1/)